# Token with whitelist function, that would only whitelisted addresses to trade the token while trading is disabled

Tags: solidity, erc-20, tokens

I want to create a token and add liquidity but only whitelisted addresses would able to trade the token while trading is disabled. If trading is enabled that means everyone can trade it but if it is disabled, only whitelisted addresses should be able to trade it.

```
contract MyToken is Context, IERC20, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Address for address;

    mapping(address => bool) whitelistedAddresses;

    address payable public marketingAddress =
        payable(0x3c48FB01CA1612EF96ed6faf667e56fA419206eC); // Marketing Address
        
    address payable public teamAddress =
        payable(0x95Bd85E2f9bb419CA6717561741c71d6b97D671c); // Team Address

    address payable public devAddress =
        payable(0x8AE0CCa9303554C0fdC0E013829fD9394deA826D); // Dev Address

    address payable public liquidityAddress =
        payable(0x3039cBa1a0065849A2C99a75DA3C0D5881b529F0); // Liquidity Address
        
    address public immutable deadAddress =
        0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD; // dead address
        
    mapping(address => uint256) private _rOwned;
    mapping(address => uint256) private _tOwned;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    mapping(address => bool) private _isExcludedFromFee;

    mapping(address => bool) private _isExcluded;
    address[] private _excluded;
    
    uint256 private constant MAX = ~uint256(0);
    uint256 private constant _tTotal = 30 *  10**6 * 1e9; // 30 million tokens
    uint256 private _rTotal = (MAX - (MAX % _tTotal));
    uint256 private _tFeeTotal;

    string private constant _name = "My TOKEN";
    string private constant _symbol = "MVY ";
    uint8 private constant _decimals = 9;
    
    uint256 private constant BUY = 1;
    uint256 private constant SELL = 2;
    uint256 private constant TRANSFER = 3;
    uint256 private buyOrSellSwitch;

    uint256 private _taxFee;
    uint256 private _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;

    uint256 private _liquidityFee;
    uint256 private _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;

    // BUY TAXES
    uint256 public _buyTaxFee = 0;
    uint256 public _buyLiquidityFee = 2;
    uint256 public _buyMarketingFee = 4;
    uint256 public _buyTeamFee = 2;
    // SELL TAXES
    uint256 public _sellTaxFee = 0;
    uint256 public _sellLiquidityFee = 2;
    uint256 public _sellMarketingFee = 4;
    uint256 public _sellTeamFee = 2;
    
    uint256 public tradingActiveBlock = 0; // 0 means trading is not active
    mapping(address => bool) public boughtEarly;
    uint256 public earlyBuyPenaltyEnd; // determines when snipers/bots can sell without extra penalty
    
    uint256 private _liquidityTokensToSwap;
    uint256 private _marketingTokensToSwap;
    uint256 private _teamTokensToSwap;
    
    bool private gasLimitActive = true;
    uint256 private gasPriceLimit = 500 * 1 gwei; 
    uint256 private gasMaxLimit =  1000000 * 1 gwei; // gasLeft limit
    
    // store addresses that a automatic market maker pairs. Any transfer *to* these addresses
    // could be subject to a maximum transfer amount
    mapping (address => bool) public automatedMarketMakerPairs;

    uint256 public maxWalletAmount;
    uint256 private minimumTokensBeforeSwap = _tTotal * 5 / 10000; // 0.05%

    IUniswapV2Router02 public uniswapV2Router;
    address public uniswapV2Pair;

    bool inSwapAndLiquify;
    bool public swapAndLiquifyEnabled = false;
    bool public tradingActive = false;

        // Whitelisted wallets and their purchase limits
    mapping(address => uint256) public whitelist;
    
    uint256 public maxWhitelistPurchase = 1 * 10**6 * 10**9; // Maximum purchase for whitelisted wallets

    event SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(bool enabled);
    event SwapAndLiquify(
        uint256 tokensSwapped,
        uint256 ethReceived,
        uint256 tokensIntoLiquidity
    );

    event SwapETHForTokens(uint256 amountIn, address[] path);

    event SwapTokensForETH(uint256 amountIn, address[] path);
    
    event SetAutomatedMarketMakerPair(address pair, bool value);
    
    event ExcludeFromReward(address excludedAddress);
    
    event IncludeInReward(address includedAddress);
    
    event ExcludeFromFee(address excludedAddress);
    
    event IncludeInFee(address includedAddress);
    
    event SetBuyFee(uint256 marketingFee, uint256 liquidityFee, uint256 reflectFee, uint256 teamFee);
    
    event SetSellFee(uint256 marketingFee, uint256 liquidityFee, uint256 reflectFee, uint256 teamFee);
    
    event TransferForeignToken(address token, uint256 amount);
    
    event UpdatedMarketingAddress(address marketing);
    
    event UpdatedLiquidityAddress(address liquidity);
    
    event UpdatedTeamAddress(address Team);
    
    event OwnerForcedSwapBack(uint256 timestamp);
    
    event BoughtEarly(address indexed sniper);
    
    event RemovedSniper(address indexed notsnipersupposedly);

    event UpdatedRouter(address indexed newrouter);
    
    modifier lockTheSwap() {
        inSwapAndLiquify = true;
        _;
        inSwapAndLiquify = false;
    }

    modifier isWhitelisted(address _address) {
    require(whitelistedAddresses[_address], "You need to be whitelisted");
    _;
    }

    constructor() {
        _rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal;

        
        IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(
            0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E // mainnet router
            //0x9Ac64Cc6e4415144C455BD8E4837Fea55603e5c3  // testnet router
        );
        address _uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory())
            .createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());

        uniswapV2Router = _uniswapV2Router;
        uniswapV2Pair = _uniswapV2Pair;
        
        _setAutomatedMarketMakerPair(_uniswapV2Pair, true);

        maxWalletAmount = 50 * 1e6 * 1e9;

        _isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[address(this)] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[marketingAddress] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[liquidityAddress] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[teamAddress] = true;
        
        emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _tTotal);
    }

    function name() external pure returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() external pure returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() external pure returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }

    function totalSupply() external pure override returns (uint256) {
        return _tTotal;
    }

    function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
        if (_isExcluded[account]) return _tOwned[account];
        return tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
    }

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount)
        external
        override
        returns (bool)
    {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender)
        external
        view
        override
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount)
        external
        override
        returns (bool)
    {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) external override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(
            sender,
            _msgSender(),
            _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(
                amount,
                "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"
            )
        );
        return true;
    }

    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue)
        external
        virtual
        returns (bool)
    {
        _approve(
            _msgSender(),
            spender,
            _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].add(addedValue)
        );
        return true;
    }

    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue)
        external
        virtual
        returns (bool)
    {
        _approve(
            _msgSender(),
            spender,
            _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].sub(
                subtractedValue,
                "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero"
            )
        );
        return true;
    }

    function isExcludedFromReward(address account)
        external
        view
        returns (bool)
    {
        return _isExcluded[account];
    }

    function totalFees() external view returns (uint256) {
        return _tFeeTotal;
    }
    
    function enableTrading() external onlyOwner {
        tradingActive = true;
        swapAndLiquifyEnabled = true;
        tradingActiveBlock = block.number;
        earlyBuyPenaltyEnd = block.timestamp + 72 hours;
    }
    function disableTrading() external onlyOwner {
        tradingActive = false;
        swapAndLiquifyEnabled = true;
        tradingActiveBlock = block.number;
        earlyBuyPenaltyEnd = block.timestamp + 72 hours;
    }

    function addUser(address _addressToWhitelist) public onlyOwner {
    whitelistedAddresses[_addressToWhitelist] = true;
    }

    function verifyUser(address _whitelistedAddress) public view returns(bool) {
    bool userIsWhitelisted = whitelistedAddresses[_whitelistedAddress];
    return userIsWhitelisted;
    }
    
    function minimumTokensBeforeSwapAmount() external view returns (uint256) {
        return minimumTokensBeforeSwap;
    }
    
    function setAutomatedMarketMakerPair(address pair, bool value) external onlyOwner {
        require(pair != uniswapV2Pair, "The pair cannot be removed from automatedMarketMakerPairs");

        _setAutomatedMarketMakerPair(pair, value);
    }

    function _setAutomatedMarketMakerPair(address pair, bool value) private {
        automatedMarketMakerPairs[pair] = value;
        if(value){excludeFromReward(pair);}
        if(!value){includeInReward(pair);}
    }
    
    function setProtectionSettings(bool antiGas) external onlyOwner() {
        gasLimitActive = antiGas;
    }
    
    function setGasPriceLimit(uint256 gas) external onlyOwner {
        require(gas >= 75);
        gasPriceLimit = gas * 1 gwei;
    }
    
    function setGasMaxLimit(uint256 gas) external onlyOwner {
        require(gas >= 750000);
        gasMaxLimit = gas * gasPriceLimit;
    }
    

    function reflectionFromToken(uint256 tAmount, bool deductTransferFee)
        external
        view
        returns (uint256)
    {
        require(tAmount <= _tTotal, "Amount must be less than supply");
        if (!deductTransferFee) {
            (uint256 rAmount, , , , , ) = _getValues(tAmount);
            return rAmount;
        } else {
            (, uint256 rTransferAmount, , , , ) = _getValues(tAmount);
            return rTransferAmount;
        }
    }

    function tokenFromReflection(uint256 rAmount)
        public
        view
        returns (uint256)
    {
        require(
            rAmount <= _rTotal,
            "Amount must be less than total reflections"
        );
        uint256 currentRate = _getRate();
        return rAmount.div(currentRate);
    }

    function excludeFromReward(address account) public onlyOwner {
        require(!_isExcluded[account], "Account is already excluded");
        require(_excluded.length + 1 <= 50, "Cannot exclude more than 50 accounts.  Include a previously excluded address.");
        if (_rOwned[account] > 0) {
            _tOwned[account] = tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
        }
        _isExcluded[account] = true;
        _excluded.push(account);
    }

    function includeInReward(address account) public onlyOwner {
        require(_isExcluded[account], "Account is not excluded");
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _excluded.length; i++) {
            if (_excluded[i] == account) {
                _excluded[i] = _excluded[_excluded.length - 1];
                _tOwned[account] = 0;
                _isExcluded[account] = false;
                _excluded.pop();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
 
    function _approve(
        address owner,
        address spender,
        uint256 amount
    ) private {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

    function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) private {
        require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
        require(amount > 0, "Transfer amount must be greater than zero");
        
        if(!tradingActive){
            require(_isExcludedFromFee[from] || _isExcludedFromFee[to], "Trading is not active yet.");
        }
         // Check if trading is active, or the wallet is whitelisted
        if ((from != owner() && to != owner()) || (!whitelistedAddresses[to] && !whitelistedAddresses[from])) {
            revert("Trading is not yet enabled");
        }

        // Check the maximum wallet amount
        if (to != owner() && to != address(0) && to != address(0xdead) && to != uniswapV2Pair) {
            uint256 walletBalance = balanceOf(to);
            require(walletBalance + amount <= maxWalletAmount, "Wallet amount exceeds the maximum limit");
        }

        // Apply whitelisted purchase limit
        if (whitelist[to] > 0) {
            require(amount <= whitelist[to], "Whitelisted purchase limit exceeded");
            whitelist[to] -= amount;
        }
        
        if(from != owner() && to != uniswapV2Pair && block.number == tradingActiveBlock){
            boughtEarly[to] = true;
        }

        if (automatedMarketMakerPairs[from] && !_isExcludedFromFee[from] && !_isExcludedFromFee[to]) {
            uint256 contractBalanceRecepient = balanceOf(to);
            require(contractBalanceRecepient + amount <= maxWalletAmount, "Exceeds maximum wallet token amount.");
        }
        
        // only use to prevent sniper buys in the first blocks.
        if (gasLimitActive && automatedMarketMakerPairs[from]) {
            require(tx.gasprice <= gasPriceLimit, "Gas price exceeds limit.");
            if(!inSwapAndLiquify && !_isExcludedFromFee[from] && !_isExcludedFromFee[to]) {
                require(gasleft() <= gasMaxLimit);
            }
        }
   
        uint256 totalTokensToSwap = _liquidityTokensToSwap + _marketingTokensToSwap + _teamTokensToSwap;
        uint256 contractTokenBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
        bool overMinimumTokenBalance = contractTokenBalance >= minimumTokensBeforeSwap;

        // swap and liquify
        if (
            !inSwapAndLiquify &&
            swapAndLiquifyEnabled &&
            balanceOf(uniswapV2Pair) > 0 &&
            totalTokensToSwap > 0 &&
            !_isExcludedFromFee[to] &&
            !_isExcludedFromFee[from] &&
            automatedMarketMakerPairs[to] &&
            overMinimumTokenBalance
        ) {
            swapBack();
        }

        bool takeFee = true;

        // If any account belongs to _isExcludedFromFee account then remove the fee
        if (_isExcludedFromFee[from] || _isExcludedFromFee[to]) {
            takeFee = false;
            buyOrSellSwitch = TRANSFER;
        } else {
            // Buy
            if (automatedMarketMakerPairs[from] ) {
                removeAllFee();
                _taxFee = _buyTaxFee;
                _liquidityFee = _buyLiquidityFee + _buyMarketingFee + _buyTeamFee;
                if(_liquidityFee > 0){
                    buyOrSellSwitch = BUY;
                }
            } 
            // Sell
            else if (automatedMarketMakerPairs[to]) {
                removeAllFee();
                _taxFee = _sellTaxFee;
                _liquidityFee = _sellLiquidityFee + _sellMarketingFee + _sellTeamFee;
                if(_liquidityFee > 0){
                    buyOrSellSwitch = SELL;
                }
                // triple tax if bought in the same block as trading active for 72 hours
                if(boughtEarly[from]  && earlyBuyPenaltyEnd <= block.number){
                    _taxFee = _taxFee * 3;
                    _liquidityFee = _liquidityFee * 3;
                }
            // Normal transfers do not get taxed
            } else {
                removeAllFee();
                buyOrSellSwitch = TRANSFER;
            }
        }
        
        _tokenTransfer(from, to, amount, takeFee);
        
    }

      // Function to add or update a whitelist entry
    function updateWhitelist(address _address, uint256 _purchaseLimit) external onlyOwner {
        whitelist[_address] = _purchaseLimit;
    }

    function swapBack() private lockTheSwap {
        uint256 contractBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
        uint256 totalTokensToSwap = _liquidityTokensToSwap.add(_teamTokensToSwap).add(_marketingTokensToSwap);
        
        // Halve the amount of liquidity tokens
        uint256 tokensForLiquidity = _liquidityTokensToSwap.div(2);
        uint256 amountToSwapForBNB = contractBalance.sub(tokensForLiquidity);
        
        uint256 initialBNBBalance = address(this).balance;

        swapTokensForBNB(amountToSwapForBNB); 
        
        uint256 bnbBalance = address(this).balance.sub(initialBNBBalance);
        
        uint256 bnbForMarketing = bnbBalance.mul(_marketingTokensToSwap).div(totalTokensToSwap);
        uint256 bnbForTeam = bnbBalance.mul(_teamTokensToSwap).div(totalTokensToSwap);
        
        uint256 bnbForLiquidity = bnbBalance.sub(bnbForMarketing).sub(bnbForTeam);
        
        uint256 bnbForDev = bnbForMarketing * 5 / 100;
        bnbForMarketing -= bnbForDev;
        
        _liquidityTokensToSwap = 0;
        _marketingTokensToSwap = 0;
        _teamTokensToSwap = 0;
        
        (bool success,) = address(teamAddress).call{value: bnbForTeam}("");
        (success,) = address(marketingAddress).call{value: bnbForMarketing}("");
        (success,) = address(devAddress).call{value: bnbForDev}("");
        
        if(tokensForLiquidity > 0 && bnbForLiquidity > 0){
            addLiquidity(tokensForLiquidity, bnbForLiquidity);
            emit SwapAndLiquify(amountToSwapForBNB, bnbForLiquidity, tokensForLiquidity);
        }
        
        // any remnants after adding liquidity send to Marketing wallet
        (success,) = address(marketingAddress).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
    }
    
    function swapTokensForBNB(uint256 tokenAmount) private {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenAmount,
            0, // accept any amount of ETH
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }
    
    function addLiquidity(uint256 tokenAmount, uint256 ethAmount) private {
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);
        uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: ethAmount}(
            address(this),
            tokenAmount,
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            liquidityAddress,
            block.timestamp
        );
    }

    function _tokenTransfer(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount,
        bool takeFee
    ) private {
        if (!takeFee) removeAllFee();

        if (_isExcluded[sender] && !_isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferFromExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else if (!_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferToExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else if (_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferBothExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else {
            _transferStandard(sender, recipient, amount);
        }

        restoreAllFee();
    }

    function _transferStandard(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 tAmount
    ) private {
        (
            uint256 rAmount,
            uint256 rTransferAmount,
            uint256 rFee,
            uint256 tTransferAmount,
            uint256 tFee,
            uint256 tLiquidity
        ) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }

    function _transferToExcluded(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 tAmount
    ) private {
        (
            uint256 rAmount,
            uint256 rTransferAmount,
            uint256 rFee,
            uint256 tTransferAmount,
            uint256 tFee,
            uint256 tLiquidity
        ) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _tOwned[recipient] = _tOwned[recipient].add(tTransferAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }

    function _transferFromExcluded(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 tAmount
    ) private {
        (
            uint256 rAmount,
            uint256 rTransferAmount,
            uint256 rFee,
            uint256 tTransferAmount,
            uint256 tFee,
            uint256 tLiquidity
        ) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }

    function _transferBothExcluded(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 tAmount
    ) private {
        (
            uint256 rAmount,
            uint256 rTransferAmount,
            uint256 rFee,
            uint256 tTransferAmount,
            uint256 tFee,
            uint256 tLiquidity
        ) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _tOwned[recipient] = _tOwned[recipient].add(tTransferAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }

    function _reflectFee(uint256 rFee, uint256 tFee) private {
        _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rFee);
        _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tFee);
    }

    function _getValues(uint256 tAmount)
        private
        view
        returns (
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256
        )
    {
        (
            uint256 tTransferAmount,
            uint256 tFee,
            uint256 tLiquidity
        ) = _getTValues(tAmount);
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRValues(
            tAmount,
            tFee,
            tLiquidity,
            _getRate()
        );
        return (
            rAmount,
            rTransferAmount,
            rFee,
            tTransferAmount,
            tFee,
            tLiquidity
        );
    }

    function _getTValues(uint256 tAmount)
        private
        view
        returns (
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256
        )
    {
        uint256 tFee = calculateTaxFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tLiquidity = calculateLiquidityFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tTransferAmount = tAmount.sub(tFee).sub(tLiquidity);
        return (tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity);
    }

    function _getRValues(
        uint256 tAmount,
        uint256 tFee,
        uint256 tLiquidity,
        uint256 currentRate
    )
        private
        pure
        returns (
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256
        )
    {
        uint256 rAmount = tAmount.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rFee = tFee.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rLiquidity = tLiquidity.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rTransferAmount = rAmount.sub(rFee).sub(rLiquidity);
        return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee);
    }

    function _getRate() private view returns (uint256) {
        (uint256 rSupply, uint256 tSupply) = _getCurrentSupply();
        return rSupply.div(tSupply);
    }

    function _getCurrentSupply() private view returns (uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 rSupply = _rTotal;
        uint256 tSupply = _tTotal;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _excluded.length; i++) {
            if (
                _rOwned[_excluded[i]] > rSupply ||
                _tOwned[_excluded[i]] > tSupply
            ) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
            rSupply = rSupply.sub(_rOwned[_excluded[i]]);
            tSupply = tSupply.sub(_tOwned[_excluded[i]]);
        }
        if (rSupply < _rTotal.div(_tTotal)) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
        return (rSupply, tSupply);
    }

    function _takeLiquidity(uint256 tLiquidity) private {
        if(buyOrSellSwitch == BUY){
            _liquidityTokensToSwap += tLiquidity * _buyLiquidityFee / _liquidityFee;
            _teamTokensToSwap += tLiquidity * _buyTeamFee / _liquidityFee;
            _marketingTokensToSwap += tLiquidity * _buyMarketingFee / _liquidityFee;
        } else if(buyOrSellSwitch == SELL){
            _liquidityTokensToSwap += tLiquidity * _sellLiquidityFee / _liquidityFee;
            _teamTokensToSwap += tLiquidity * _sellTeamFee / _liquidityFee;
            _marketingTokensToSwap += tLiquidity * _sellMarketingFee / _liquidityFee;
        }
        uint256 currentRate = _getRate();
        uint256 rLiquidity = tLiquidity.mul(currentRate);
        _rOwned[address(this)] = _rOwned[address(this)].add(rLiquidity);
        if (_isExcluded[address(this)])
            _tOwned[address(this)] = _tOwned[address(this)].add(tLiquidity);
    }

    function calculateTaxFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
        return _amount.mul(_taxFee).div(10**2);
    }

    function calculateLiquidityFee(uint256 _amount)
        private
        view
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return _amount.mul(_liquidityFee).div(10**2);
    }

    function removeAllFee() private {
        if (_taxFee == 0 && _liquidityFee == 0) return;

        _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;
        _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;

        _taxFee = 0;
        _liquidityFee = 0;
    }

    function restoreAllFee() private {
        _taxFee = _previousTaxFee;
        _liquidityFee = _previousLiquidityFee;
    }

    function isExcludedFromFee(address account) external view returns (bool) {
        return _isExcludedFromFee[account];
    }

    function excludeFromFee(address account) external onlyOwner {
        _isExcludedFromFee[account] = true;
        emit ExcludeFromFee(account);
    }

    function includeInFee(address account) external onlyOwner {
        _isExcludedFromFee[account] = false;
        emit IncludeInFee(account);
    }
    
    function removeBoughtEarly(address account) external onlyOwner {
        boughtEarly[account] = false;
        emit RemovedSniper(account);
    }

   }
```

This is my current contract, But its not working. I would love to know what I'm doing wrong and how I can implement these features

```
//This is in response to @albert comment
```

The problem is I'm not getting any specific error message. In remix when I tried deploying to the vm, I get this error

```
creation of MyToken errored: Error occured: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

And when I tried using hardhat to deploy the contract, it threw this error

```
ProviderError: Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string
```

Here's the link to full solidity file
[Github repo](https://github.com/ccurves/token-contract)

Comment: Instead of pasting the whole contract you could point to a github repo, or limit the contract to the functions causing error, so it can be reproduced easily.

Comment: Alright, would do that now

Comment: "It's not working" is too vague. What's not working? If you call it, do you get a wrong return value? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

One of the errors is that it exceeds the max code size. Try to remove unnecessary code or deploye seperately and then linking them.

Comment: I did that when deploying with hardhat, separated all the libraries but it still didn't deploy

Comment: Deploy the uniswap functionality contracts seprately and use it as interface in other contract.